# How do I pass id of post request from mid to the top layer to return it in header location 201?

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2

So, basically. I have 3 layers in my app: low, mid and the top. Top is for controllers and mid for some logic. The problem.is that whenever I add something to database and got the id on the mid layer, ive got no idea how to let the top controller layer know about it, so that I could put it into header location as a response with status code 201. If more info is needed, let me know. Using EF if it helps. And I do not wanna to pass httpcontext down.

Comment: Have the mid layer function return either the model that was saved with updated id or just return the id. that way the top layer now has the id to do with as it desires. Without a proper [mcve] that better describes your problem, there is not mush else that can be suggested.

Answer (score 0):

As I heard you want to add some data with mid layer and top layer should know about this.

I would do this that : 
Top layer should handle dbcontext for data transfering.
Mid Layer should handle data (models) for Top Layer.

if you have some code share  and answer will be concrete

Comment: Sorry for no concrete examples but Im on my phone. Basically mid layer receives model from  top lvl, which is after saved in the mid. And mid knows the id of saved thing. Problem is that ive no idea how let top(controller) layer let know about that id, so that I could return it. It is rest api